# What is the correct way to partition relation table by date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, partitioning

I am creating a DB with admin panel for my youth organisation. The DB is created using PostgreSQL and the DB control panel for admins is being developed in ASP.NET using C#.

As you can see in the [E-R model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ampht.png) and [relation schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVdKB.png), there is a **Person table**, a **Unit table** (Unit example: student group) and a **table BelongsToUnit**, which is a relation table to store which person belongs to which unit. One Person can belong to many units.

So the problem is when a person belongs to a unit few years in a row, he would to added many times to the same **BelongsToUnit table** only with different Start and End dates, there would be some data dublication.

***Is the correct way to solve this by partitioning table by year or something? If yes, how can it be done in PostegreSQL? Would it automatically create new table every year?***

P.S. The tables will be controlled using EntityFrameworkCore inside ASP.NET app.

The current **BelongsToUnit table** create:

```postgreSQL
CREATE TABLE AF.BelongsToUnit (
    Id              INTEGER         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
                                    GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    PersonId        INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    UnitId          INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    Position        VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL 
                                    CHECK (Position IN ('globėjas', 'narys'))
                                    DEFAULT 'narys',
    StartDate       DATE            NOT NULL,
    EndDate         DATE            NOT NULL 
                                    CHECK (EndDate >= StartDate),

    CONSTRAINT FK_Person_BelongsToUnit_PersonId 
        FOREIGN KEY (PersonId) REFERENCES AF.Person(Id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Unit_BelongsToUnit_UnitId 
        FOREIGN KEY (UnitId) REFERENCES AF.Unit(Id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);
```

Comment: "So the problem is when a person belongs to a unit few years in a row, he would to added many times to the same BelongsToUnit table only with different Start and End dates, there would be some data dublication." Why do you need the multiple records? Is there some perceived problem with having a person to unit record with a start and end date spanning several years? Not sure I understand what your problem is

Comment: @MattSmirth That is a good catch! I think you are correct, there is no problem:) Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need table partitioning? What problem should it solve for you? How many billion records do you expect?